# Why is Next.js ignoring environment variable passed through docker-compose?

Tags: next.js

I have build a docker image and am using docker-compose for running the application.

The app is using the env from .env.local which was available during the docker build.

Even passing custom environment variable mapping as volume is ignored by the application.

Also env from docker-compose is ignored.

How do.I get it working?

The env from docker composw

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.